# Why can't the daughter go into the basement?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-quiet-place

In *A Quiet Place*, Lee Abbott (John Krasinski's character) won't let his deaf daughter go down into the basement?  Why?  She even hesitates going down there when her mom and brother are running from the monsters at the end of the movie.  Her brother doesn't hesitate going down the stairs, but she does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a lot of the contents of the basement were things that could make noise -- including radios and other equipment. Since she was deaf, she could easily trigger a noise that would expose them without even realizing this.

She tries to defend herself when her father tells her to not enter the basement: "I'm not a child! I won't make a sound!"

[image: "I'm not a child! I won't make a sound!"]

(Also: she already had shown she didn't always follow their instructions, causing them problems.)